# Ready to use Image for SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin

I have a requirement in which I am required to have a ready to use image of the SharePoint 2013 development environment with all the necessary installations like SQL server, language pack, etc and configurations already done- App configuration, service application configuration, search configuration etc, which the developers can directly use by either mounting it or by running it and right away start the development.

The environment can be considered here is single server environment with all the tiers in the same server. However any suggestions for the multi-server environment will also be helpful.

Thanks